# make NSAttributeString backroundColor to cover all label area?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

inside the yellow area there is label.
Is there way to make the NSAttributeString to "stretch" and cover all the label ? 
meaning the all label will get the pink background color (of the string) ?
[image]

Comment: Only if you can fill the entire label with text.

Comment: I know that's not what you're looking for, because I'm not sure you can achieve this via `NSAttributedString`, but can't you what you want with `label.backgroundColor = ...` ?

Comment: @Zaphod
I can, but I need to check the NSAttriubteString for the current background color ATTRIBUTE and then set it to the label.backgroundColor. for such a basic thing that occurs 10000000 times in app, I wanted to make sure I'm not missing something and there is no other way that anyone know besides me :)

Comment: What about a label subclass overriding the `attributedString` `didSet` function that checks the string background color and set it to the label `backgroundColor`. This way you won't miss anywhere.

Comment: @Zaphod I subclass the label and it work the way I explained in the last comment.
but I just needed to be sure there is no "system" way that I'm missing. Thanks.